# Cytoscape is not picking up some events when the app is running in the shadow DOM

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have an app that runs fully within the shadow DOM. However I have noticed that some Cytoscape events are not being picked up, for example 'tapdragover' is not being picked up while 'tapselect' is being picked up normally.

Any settings or tips to get a Cytoscape instance to run normally within a shadow DOM?

Thanks.

> this.cy.on('tapdrag', handler)
> Is not being picked up while it works normally when I don't use the shadow DOM.